# Javascript window.close on mobile

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm developing a small web app using ASP.NET. One of my function in this system is to open a new window tab, I've put a button close after they save the document but it seems it's only working on desktop.

Here's my code.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Close" OnClientClick="javascript: window.close();"/>
```

I'm using Opera mini as a browser in my mobile (SIII).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Close" OnClientClick="return self.close();"/>
```

Comment: Hi Amit, just the same. Can't close it in my mobile and windows(browser Chrome) but in IE it's working fine. Anyway, my goal is to close it in my mobile. Is there anything? :(

Answer (score 2):

I fear you're out of luck, Opera Mini browser won't let you close windows with JavaScript, by design.

Taken from the [official documentation](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-mini-and-javascript/): (emphasis mine)

> **Opening and closing windows**
>
> Opera Mini also doesn't support using JavaScript to open new windows
>   (such as window.open()). If you use window.open() to launch a new
>   window, Opera Mini will instead load that page as a new 'screen.' It
>   will not open a new window or tab. Similarly, because a new window was
>   never opened, **window.close() will not work**. (This is also true of the
>   target attribute of HTML.)

Comment: Thanks for this Shadow, I've also have a handheld which is a barcode scanner. It uses IE for the browser. But still can't use this javascript. :(

Comment: @Gimo what IE version exactly?

Comment: Hi @Shadow, I think version 6. My handheld is Windows CE 6.

Comment: @Gimo looks like a known bug, see [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979736). Install that patch and see if it help.